# Question about the fields in a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am very familiar with using Ampere's Law to find the B field inside a solenoid ($\mu_0nI(t)$).  Then I can use Faradays to find the E field inside ($\propto\dot I$).

I want to get this result this way using Maxwell's equations inside the solenoid for a harmonic current ($\Re[I_0e^{-i\omega t}]$).  Maxwells equations will be
$$\nabla\cdot E=\nabla\cdot B=0$$
$$\nabla\times E=i\omega B$$
$$\nabla \times B=-i\omega\mu\epsilon E$$
Which will reduce to $(\nabla^2+k^2)\begin{bmatrix}E\\B\end{bmatrix}=0$.  From symmetry, I know that B is only in z and E is only in $\theta$ (cylindrical coords).
When I solve the equation for B, since $\nabla\cdot B=0\rightarrow dB/dz=0\rightarrow B(z)=\text{Constant}$

But when I solve helmholtz equation in cylindrical coordinates, I get that
$$B=AJ_0(k\rho)$$
SO the field depends radially on location from the center.  This does not agree with the constant $\mu nI$.  Is this approach correct?  If I impose the boundary conditions, (which I am unsure of), will I get something that is not a bessel function?

EDIT: "VEry long" solenoid so edge effects are neglected

Comment: Could you give your reasoning for why the $\mathbf{B}$-field is only in the $\hat{z}$-direction and why the $\mathbf{E}$-field is only in the $\hat{\theta}$-direction?

Comment: Symmetry.  If I have current wrapped around in theta direction, then the field is in z.  Then since E is curl B, it will be in theta

Comment: You have found $\frac{d B}{dz} = 0$, this gives $B$ independent of $z$ but it may be a function of $\rho$?

Comment: You may be interested in the following reference:  *Electrically induced magnetic fields; a consistent approach* Brian Batell and Andrew Ferstl Am. J. Phys. **71**, 925 (2003)